# How to run a same code on different datasets

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, imputation, r-mice

I have seen different topics and answers on the similar-ish question on the website but almost none of them answered my question in this specific setting that I am working on.

Here is the story:

I have 20 different datasets all with the exact same variable names and I want to run a code on them. How my question is different from those that have already been answered:

The code I want to run includes some functions that I wrote where one of the necessary arguments is "data", so what I can not figure is how to call each different dataset in the argument so the functions can run!

Here is a very simple scale of what I am dealing with:

```
X1<-c(1,1,1,0,1,0)
X2<c(0,1,1,0,0,0)
data1<-data.frame(X1,X2)
X1_1<- c(1,0,1,0,1,0)
X2_2<- c(1,1,0,0,0,0)
data2<-data.frame(X1_1,X2_2)
colnames(data2)<- c("X1", "X2")   # to rename the variables to become the same as data1

#The function

f1<- function(model1,model2,data){

d1=subset(data, X1==1)
p<- glm(model1, family= "binomial", data=d1)
pp<- predict (p, newdata=data, type="response")

q<- glm( model2, family= "binomial", data=data)
qq<- predict(q, newdata=data, type="response")

m=qq*pp

list<- list(m=m, pp=pp, qq=qq)

return(list)
}

f2<- function (model1, model2,data){

k<- glm(model1, family= "binomial", data=data)
kk<- predict (k, newdata=data, type="response")

j<- glm( model2, family= "binomial", data=data)
jj<- predict(j, newdata=data, type="response") 

L=kk+jj

list<- list(L=L, kk=kk, jj=jj)

return(list)
}

#The code I want to run that is supposed to use the function (now lets say for data1)

run1<- f1 (model1= X2~X1, model2= X1~X2, data=data1)
m<- run1$m

run2< -f2 (model1=X1~X2, model2, X2~X1, data=data1)
L<-run2$L

Q=m+L
```

P.S: An overall explanation is that the 20 different datasets are actually the maxit=20 in the mice package because there are lots of missing data I have to impute! Why I do not use the "with" and the "pool" ? Because as you can see, I need to do the "prediction" and mice, unfortunately, doesn't have this possibility, so the only way that I could think of was to use each of the imputed datasets and use a loop and act like it is a simulation study with 20 runs and then take the means of whatever results I want to have! So if anyone has a better solution, I would be super happy to know!

ADDED AFTER POSTING:
I am using a developed method for AIPTW and TMLE where each of them has a propensity score model and an outcome model and the developed version has 2 different functions for each of the outcome and propensity score model, after Harry asked me to edit the question to become more detailed, I am giving this explanation to just give the hint on the number of lines that the code has, this explanation raised up when the "lapply" solution was suggested.

**Update**

lapply in the suggested way does not solve this problem

Comment: Try putting your data sets into a list. Then use lapply.

Comment: @HarrySmith I still have that question though! Let's say I did, when I use apply(list of data, function_1) how does it know to put the data argument equal to the first data set in the list and then second and so on! This may sound like a naive question but Im somewhat new to R, so I have no pre-imagination

Comment: @Aura that's a really good question to ask. If you call lapply(list(a, b, c), f), you will get back a list of the same length as before, but with the function applied to each item in the list... list(f(a), f(b), f(c)). Does that answer your question?

Comment: @BillO'Brien Yeah many thanks! That totally makes sense!! However, that makes me think if I should rename the data argument in a way it becomes similar to the data lists? Or there is absolutely no need to do it! (I'm going to run the code to see if I can practically get the answer ASAP as I'm waiting to get a new set of imputed datasets and it is still running)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. I can't test it, because I don't know what the model1 and model2 objects are that will be passed to the function. You will see that the names of the list elements match the names of the data frames. `lapply` loops through the list object it has been given in order.

```
X1<-c(1,1,1,0,1,0)
X2<-c(0,1,1,0,0,0)
data1<-data.frame(X1,X2)
X1_1<- c(1,0,1,0,1,0)
X2_2<- c(1,1,0,0,0,0)
data2<-data.frame(X1_1,X2_2)
colnames(data2)<- c("X1", "X2")   # to rename the variables to become the same as data1

#The function

#The function

f1<- function(model1,model2,data){
  
  d1=subset(data, X1==1)
  p<- glm(model1, family= "binomial", data=d1)
  pp<- predict (p, newdata=data, type="response")
  
  q<- glm( model2, family= "binomial", data=data)
  qq<- predict(q, newdata=data, type="response")
  
  m=qq*pp
  
  list<- list(m=m, pp=pp, qq=qq)
  
  return(list)
}

dat_in <- list("df1" = data1,
               "df2" = data2)

fun1_out <- lapply(dat_in, FUN = function(x)f1(model1= X2~X1, model2= X1~X2, x))
fun2_out <- lapply(dat_in, FUN = function(x)f2(model1= X2~X1, model2= X1~X2, x))
```

fun1_out will be a list containing the output from f1 for all data sets in dat_in. The same goes for fun2_out and so on for as many functions as you like.

Comment: Thanks Harry, but the problem is  I have 7 more functions and aside from that, when I want to use the functions it is not just a one-line code, I have around 200 lines that happens after using the functions, how am I suppose to also consider them while using lapply? I dont think I can do it

Comment: Idk what you mean by "i have 200 lines that happens after using each function". Maybe you can edit your question to be more targeted to what you need as a final product.

Comment: I just updated with some explanations of what really is going on, hope it clarifies it a bit more.

Comment: I madde a small edit. You can use the lappy method for N number of functions, the extract whatever values you need for ```Q=m+L```. If you don't want to do that individually, you can also use lapply there as well.

Comment: Thanks Harry! I however got an error which I assume is because of some extreme wights so I first have to figure a way to learn how to truncate weights because I never did it before, and then see if it runs. Thank you for the sincere helful answer which I hope everyone else can also use!

Comment: I wanted to mention that the code didn't do what I expected so it is not the answer to this question, the issue still remains with "how to call the argument: data=data"